# Hey, I want the second options. get_post_meta()

Tags: post-meta

I can loop through foreach, but I don't know the second, "My car", "My boat" etc. I want my question is this:

car - My car,
boat - My boat,
bike - My bike

```
$engine = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "engine", false);
foreach ($engine as $key => $val) {
  echo $val;
}
```

That is fine, the first $val - car, boat, bike.
Not the second "My car, My boat, My bike".

```
$engine = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "engine", false);
foreach ($engine as $key => $val) {
  echo $val." - "."My car"." - "."My boat"." - "."My bike";
}
```

This is wrong.

```
$engine = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "engine", false);
foreach ($engine as $key => $val) {
  if(array_keys($engine, "car")) {
    echo $val." - "."My car";
  }
  if(array_keys($engine, "boat")) {
    echo $val." - "."My boat";
  }
  if(array_keys($engine, "bike")) {
    echo $val." - "."My bike";
  }
}
```

And this is also wrong:

car - My car,
car - My boat,
car - My bike,

boat - My car,
boat - My boat,
boat - My bike,

bike - My car,
bike - My boat,
bike - My bike,

Comment: try that `foreach ($engine as $key => $val) { echo "$key : $val<br/>";}`

Comment: Can you rephrase your wording? I couldn't understand what was meant, and it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what a correct output would look like

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you have a post meta which will return you your vehicle type and based on this you wish to create something like:

> $vehicle_type - My $vehicle type

If you are not venturing into categorization of vehicle after vehicle type then the below mentioned code should work fine.

```
foreach ($engine as $key => $val) {
    echo $val . ' - My ' . $val . ', ';
}
```

If you want a structure like

> car - My Batmobile, boat - My nautilus, bike - My hoverbike

and your are sure of what value to put based on vehicle type, then this code should work

```
foreach ($engine as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == 'car') {
        echo $val . ' - My batmobile, ';
    }
    if ($val == 'boat') {
        echo $val . ' - My nautilus, ';
    }
    if ($val == 'bike') {
        echo $val . ' - My hoverbike';
    }

}
```